# FastAPI and database

Tags: docker, mariadb, fastapi

I am starting with docker and i have implemented a database mariadb with other services (adminer, connected to wordpress and nginx..) and i am now trying to run an api with python where my data will be "stored" in my mariadb database. My issue there is that i cant reach connection to it, returning an error

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'victor'@'%'
ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'victor_api'@'%'
ERROR 1007 (HY000) at line 1: Can't create database 'wordpress'; database exists
2023-07-17  8:55:35 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.3.39-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 source revision ca001cf2048f0152689e1895e2dc15486dd0b1af as process 240
2023-07-17  8:55:35 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't lock aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' for exclusive use, error: 11. Will retry for 30 seconds
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

When i get an access to my database, users victor and victor_api are well there, like my database is databases. So i tried to implement a way to "destroy" user and then create it again, flushing the same privileges in my python script in my function create_tables :

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
import mysql.connector
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import json

app = FastAPI()

# Get the current working directory
current_dir = os.getcwd()
# Construct the path to the .env file
dotenv_path = os.path.join(current_dir, '.env')
# Load environment variables from the .env file
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

@dataclass
class Channel:
    id: str
    name: str
    tags: list[str] = field(default_factory=list)
    description: str = ""


def get_db_connection():
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=os.getenv('BDD_HOST'),
        # user=os.getenv('API_USER'),
        user='root',
        password=os.getenv('API_USER_PASSWORD'),
        database=os.getenv('BDD_NAME')
    )
    return connection
    
def create_channels_table():
    connection = get_db_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    create_table_query = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS channels (
        id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(255),
        tags VARCHAR(255),
        description TEXT
    );
    """
    cursor.execute(create_table_query)
    connection.commit()
    # Check if user 'victor_api' already exists
    cursor.execute("SELECT User FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'victor_api'")
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    print(result)
    if result:
        # User 'victor_api' exists, delete it
        cursor.execute("DROP USER 'victor_api'@'%'")
        print("Deleted existing user: 'victor_api'")
        cursor.execute("FLUSH PRIVILEGES;")
        cursor.execute("SELECT User FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'victor_api'")
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        print(result)
        connection.commit()
    # Create a new user 'victor_api'
    create_user_query = "CREATE USER 'victor_api'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123'"
    cursor.execute(create_user_query)
    cursor.execute("FLUSH PRIVILEGES;")
    cursor.execute("SELECT User FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'victor_api'")
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result:
        print(result)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()


def insert_channel_into_db(channel: Channel):
    connection = get_db_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = "SELECT id FROM channels WHERE id = %s"
    cursor.execute(query, (channel.id,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result:
        print("Channel already exists:", channel.id)
    else:
        insert_query = """
        INSERT INTO channels (id, name, tags, description)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)
        """
        values = (channel.id, channel.name, ', '.join(channel.tags), channel.description)
        cursor.execute(insert_query, values)
        connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()


def fill_database_from_file():
    with open('channels.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        channels_to_add = json.load(file)
        for channel_raw in channels_to_add:
            channel = Channel(**channel_raw)
            insert_channel_into_db(channel)


def get_channel_from_db(channel_id):
    connection = get_db_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = "SELECT * FROM channels WHERE id = %s"
    cursor.execute(query, (channel_id,))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    if not row:
        return None
    channel = Channel(id=row[0], name=row[1], tags=json.loads(row[2]), description=row[3])
    return channel


# Call the function to create the channels table
create_channels_table()

# Fill the database from the channels.json file when the script starts
fill_database_from_file()

# Create the FastAPI app instance
app = FastAPI()

# Define your API routes and logic
@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"message": "The server is running."}

@app.get("/channels/{channel_id}", response_model=Channel)
def read_item(channel_id: str) -> Channel:
    channel = get_channel_from_db(channel_id)
    if not channel:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Channel not found")
    return channel


# Start the FastAPI application using uvicorn
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

Any idea on that ? Thank you very much

Comment: you have two container running on the same volume. Do nothing more drastic than killing the container instance that isn't being used.

Comment: Hello @danblack, it seems that my issue is somewhere else (thanks for your answer btw) i am trying to run 2 services (wordpress and my python app) through the same mariadb databse, via the same port 3306. I tried to connected to an other port 3307 but does't work - my scripts seem ok cause each service work when running "alone" (when i get wordpress off from the network my app works and reverse)

Comment: You have two instances of mariadb running on the same datadir somehow. Locks on `/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control` aren't done by anything else. Fix this before updating beyond 10.4, as before the end of the month (next release), the [innodb self protection](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31568) is insufficient and will corrupt data.